# org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException:

Tags: android, kotlin

Error: org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Front-end Internal error: Failed to analyze declaration

Cause: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

After android studio update , not possible to run projects. how to fix this error?  Used android studio version is 3.3 and kotlin-stdlib version is 1.3.0. is it kotlin version bug or android studio bug?

```
 org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Front-end Internal error: Failed to analyze declaration
Cause: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
File being compiled at position: (48,1) in /CountrySelectActivity.kt
The root cause was thrown at: KtQualifiedExpression.kt:35
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.visitDeclaration(ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.kt:43)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitDeclaration(KtVisitorVoid.java:453)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitDeclaration(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitNamedDeclaration(KtVisitor.java:398)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitNamedDeclaration(KtVisitorVoid.java:381)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitNamedDeclaration(KtVisitorVoid.java:959)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitNamedDeclaration(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitClassOrObject(KtVisitor.java:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitClassOrObject(KtVisitorVoid.java:37)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitClassOrObject(KtVisitorVoid.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitClassOrObject(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitClass(KtVisitor.java:33)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitClass(KtVisitorVoid.java:33)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitClass(KtVisitorVoid.java:459)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitClass(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtClass.accept(KtClass.kt:34)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImplStub.accept(KtElementImplStub.java:59)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer$analyzeDeclarations$1.registerDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:78)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer$analyzeDeclarations$1.visitKtFile(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:513)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.accept(KtFile.kt:221)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.accept(KtFile.kt:208)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.visitElement(ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.kt:27)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.PsiElementVisitor.visitFile(PsiElementVisitor.java:34)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitKtFile(KtVisitor.java:73)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:69)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:513)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.accept(KtFile.kt:221)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.accept(KtFile.kt:208)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:201)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations$default(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:110)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:375)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:366)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:120)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:362)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:102)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:225)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:39)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:103)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:455)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1029)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1071)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1028)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:454)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtQualifiedExpression$DefaultImpls.getOperationTokenNode(KtQualifiedExpression.kt:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtDotQualifiedExpression.getOperationTokenNode(KtDotQualifiedExpression.kt:25)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtQualifiedExpression$DefaultImpls.getExpression(KtQualifiedExpression.kt:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtQualifiedExpression$DefaultImpls.getSelectorExpression(KtQualifiedExpression.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtDotQualifiedExpression.getSelectorExpression(KtDotQualifiedExpression.kt:55)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPackageDirective.getPackageNames(KtPackageDirective.java:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPackageDirective.getQualifiedNameOf(KtPackageDirective.java:158)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPackageDirective.getQualifiedName(KtPackageDirective.java:149)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtPackageDirective.getFqName(KtPackageDirective.java:111)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.getPackageFqNameByTree(KtFile.kt:95)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.getPackageFqName(KtFile.kt:83)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.declarations.FileBasedDeclarationProviderFactory.computeFilesByPackage(FileBasedDeclarationProviderFactory.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.declarations.FileBasedDeclarationProviderFactory.lambda$new$0(FileBasedDeclarationProviderFactory.java:47)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:354)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:410)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.declarations.FileBasedDeclarationProviderFactory.packageExists(FileBasedDeclarationProviderFactory.java:70)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.declarations.AbstractDeclarationProviderFactory.getPackageMemberDeclarationProvider(AbstractDeclarationProviderFactory.java:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ResolveSession.getPackageFragment(ResolveSession.java:213)
```

Comment: Please downgrade your kotlin-stdlib version '1.3.0' to '1.2.71' I will check in Android studio 3.2.1. it's working for me. I hope it helps for you also.

Comment: @Dhanajay   tried downgrade it not works for me.  Uninstall and install kotlin plugin , issue is fixed .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:
Uninstall and install kotlin plugin.
it Worked for me

Comment: It was the only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/snapcrafters/android-studio/issues/81#issuecomment-843622891

Answer (score 65):

This problem is solved by cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: I.e. remove your build directory and build again (Invalidating  caches and restarting will not help in Android Studio/IntelliJ)

Answer (score 24):

`Build > Rebuild Project` on intellij 2020.1 fixed it

Answer (score 12):

Go to your project folder and delete the `build` folder and the `out` folder, then retry, it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error the file was a "kotlin script"

### Kotlin script

I had `.kts` instead `.kt` extension. This probably was because the IDE only showed the "New File" > "Kotlin Script" option.

### Solution:

Renamed the file from `filename.kts` to `filename.kt`

Answer (score 3):

My answer worked :

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches` -> `Invalidate and Restart`

Answer (score 2):

Maven -> clean -> compile -> install

did it for me

Answer (score 1):

1- code > Code cleanup
2- Build > Rebuild Project on intellij 2021.2.3 fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing something very similar in my Kotlin Maven project. You have to set the version of your `kotlin-maven-plugin`

```
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem when using Android Studio Bumblebee
I solved this problem by Build —--> rebuild project